# Color shading a wind turbine blade in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am pretty new to tikz and my goal is to draw a generic wind turbine blade such that I can fill it with colors shading from green (left) to red (right)
like a colormap plot I hope you get the idea.

With my current skills I could draw the blade in a line by line fashion, but I would like to learn how to do it in a "smarter" way such that I easily can color the figure within the lines.

[image: Generic turbine blade]

Comment: Please show the code you used to draw the blade

Comment: This is just a picture, i could draw the blade but i am looking for a method to avoid drawing it line for line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With tikz `\shade` command:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shadedraw[left color=green,right color=red] (0.6315,3.6977) .. controls (0.7398,3.5492) and (0.7503,3.3778) .. (0.6550,3.3151) .. controls (0.5597,3.2523) and (0.3948,3.3219) .. (0.2865,3.4705) .. controls (0.1783,3.6190) and (0.1678,3.7903) .. (0.2631,3.8531) .. controls (0.3583,3.9158) and (0.5233,3.8463) .. (0.6315,3.6977) -- cycle
 (0.2221,3.8172) .. controls (0.2221,3.8172) and (0.6084,4.1358) .. (0.8203,4.2755) .. controls (0.8203,4.2755) and (1.1664,5.1021) .. (1.2321,5.1457) .. controls (1.3934,5.2527) and (5.8407,7.6417) .. (6.7093,8.1135) .. controls (6.7482,8.1346) and (6.8111,8.1615) .. (6.8414,8.1290) .. controls (6.8791,8.0885) and (6.8541,7.9998) .. (6.8103,7.9659) .. controls (5.0401,6.5957) and (0.6494,3.3122) .. (0.6494,3.3122);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]